# Grafana Elsatisearch Graylog (HELP)

Tags: monitoring, devops, grafana, graylog

Grafana won't pull data from elasticsearch directly. I want to search my graylog using only elasticseach and not using Search Query Language like "5b4f8c20ed7993028c6a44e3 NOT nginx_http_version: "HTTP/1.1" NOT nginx_http_version: "HTTP/1.0""

I would like to search for everything, then group by a certain field and do count but for some reason, it's not showing. I can see in Query Inspector that the results are correct, but the chart isn't shown Grafana for whatever reason.

Grafana Dashboard Screenshots: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/134652/1851554/bhC59ycbJOFMak0/upload.png
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/134652/1851554/C6mFxWGWL9FLRYM/upload.png
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/134652/1851554/zaO5bMbgJmOr4Zf/upload.png